# How to stop a flow by killswitch in a GraphDSL? and How to find the inner actor of a flow inside the Graph?

Tags: scala, websocket, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm trying to learn about akka-streams' structure in code with akka actors by poking around [this](http://blog.scalac.io/2015/07/30/websockets-server-with-akka-http.html).

There were issues I encountered during my experiments that I would like to know their whys and hows. I used asterixes and a number to point at the code:

- in *3* i used a "throttling" strategy to limit the incoming messages but when a stream gets closed it still causes a delay so I wanted to avoid that delay then tried to stop the flow with *1* and *6* but I have no idea how to use a stopper in *2*. Maybe you can help me?
- as you can see in *4* I can access to inner actor of the websocket in which I can distinguish the actor by passing it to my ChatRoomActor to maintain but I need to have the actor in *5* for the times when it quits so I can find the quitter in the context!

---

```
class ChatRoom(chatRoomActor: ActorRef, actorSystem: ActorSystem) extends ChatRoomTrait {

def websocketFlow(user_id: String): Flow[Message, Message, Any] = 
Flow.fromGraph(
GraphDSL.create(Source.actorRef[ChatMessage](bufferSize = 1000, OverflowStrategy.fail)) {
  implicit builder =>
  chatSource => 

  import GraphDSL.Implicits._
  implicit val executionContext = actorSystem.dispatcher

  var stopper = builder.add(KillSwitches.single[ChatEvent]) // ****1

  val fromWebsocket = builder.add(
    Flow[Message]
      .watchTermination()(
      (_, te) => te.onSuccess {
        case cause => // ****2
      })
      .throttle(1, 1 seconds, 1, ThrottleMode.shaping) // ****3
      //.buffer(1, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
      //.delay(1 seconds, DelayOverflowStrategy.backpressure)
      .collect {
      case TextMessage.Strict(txt) => IncomingMessage(user_id, txt)
    }
  )

  val actorAsSource = builder.materializedValue.map(actor => UserJoined(user_id+, actor)) // ****4
  val chatActorSink  = Sink.actorRef[ChatEvent](chatRoomActor, UserLeft(user_id)) // ****5
  val mergeToChat = builder.add(Merge[ChatEvent](2))

  actorAsSource ~> mergeToChat.in(0)
  fromWebsocket ~> mergeToChat.in(1)

  mergeToChat ~> stopper ~> chatActorSink //****6

  val backToWebsocket = builder.add(
    Flow[ChatMessage].groupedWithin(10, 300 millis).mapConcat {
      msgs => msgs map {
        case ChatMessage(author, text) => TextMessage(s"[$author]: $text")
      }
    }
  )

  chatSource ~> backToWebsocket

  FlowShape(fromWebsocket.in, backToWebsocket.out)
}
)}
```